# writing inside a specific column Serilog ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, serilog

I am working on Serilog in ASP.NET MVC with C#.

I have to types of log, one as for admin level and one is for user level.

I want to make an Extra column called "Role" contains 1 for admin or 2 for user according to microsoft member ship.

I used this code:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.........;

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString, "Logs")
                .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
                .Enrich.With<HttpRequestIdEnricher>()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .CreateLogger();

            Log.Information("Web4 starting");
            Log.Information("log location: {0}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

I already added the column into the database

how can I write into column after create it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ColumnOptions` allows you to tell the SQL Server sink about the column:

```
var columnOptions = new ColumnOptions
{
  AdditionalDataColumns = new Collection<DataColumn>
  {
    new DataColumn {DataType = typeof (string), ColumnName = "Role"}
  }
};
```

Passed to the logger configuration method:

```
.WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString, "Logs", columnOptions: columnOptions)
```

The data needs to be attached to each log event:

```
class RoleEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
  public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory pf)
  {
    var role = // Get the role from your identity provider
    logEvent.AddOrUpdateProperty(pf.CreateProperty("Role", role));
  }
}
```

Then configure the logger to use the enricher:

```
.Enrich.With<RoleEnricher>()
```

Comment: Is it possible to access or otherwise inject HttpContext into the RoleEnricher in this solution?  Am trying to get a userId from context, but give it its own column.  - Can create a new question if needed, thx..